# no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path exception while running akka project

Tags: akka, persistence, threadpoolexecutor, leveldb

I am trying to start an existing project from the main class. But getting the exception below.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni in java.library.path, C:\Users\Z003SXSP\AppData\Local\Temp\leveldbjni-64-1-386410980806513791.8: Can't find dependent libraries]

But when I tried running the same project from other machine, I am able to run it successfully also found `leveldbjni-64-1-386410980806513791.8` file has been created in `temp` directory. Not getting why it not able to generate that file and complaining the above resulting in `shutting down JVM` from my machine.

Attached the screenshot of the log.

[image]

TIA.

Comment: did you solve problem ?

Comment: yes, solved by provided answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable for your windows machine, that may solve your issue, refer here for more :-[link](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni/issues/41)

Comment: I'm having same issue for MacOs why installing what you're mentioning resolved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On mac M1, it didn't work for me with jdk1.8 and jdk17 versions, but when I switched to jdk11 it was fine!

My thoughts on troubleshooting
From akka's official website, I see that leveldb is used as the default persistence store, but other stores are also provided in the plugin, which can be replaced to circumvent the problem, or can be turned off with `akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.native = false`, which for some reason I couldn't do