# DataStax Studio Installation Error in windows 10

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

[While i try to install datastax studio i got this error "no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loGKv.png)

OS: windows 10

Java : jdk1.8

Datastax studio : version 2.0.0

and i also installed microsoft visual c++ 2015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path exception while running akka project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766272/no-leveldbjni64-1-8-in-java-library-path-exception-while-running-akka-project)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766272/no-leveldbjni64-1-8-in-java-library-path-exception-while-running-akka-project

Comment: Thanks so it will not work on window 7 without VC++